# Password about to expire. Can't login to site

Tags: sharepoint-server, login, password

Recently we are experiencing some issue regarding to login to SharePoint site.

the problem seems to be related to “`password ABOUT to expire`”, because they can login to a computer without a problem.   If an account is already expired, then computer will prompt them to change it.   Yes, it only happens in SharePoint.

is this a known issue in SharePoint? or any workaround to allow them access the sharepoint when their passwords are about to expire, but are not expired yet?

any feedback please?

Answer (score 0):

As Long as it is not expired, they should be able to log in in SharePoint. As soon as it IS expired, the username/Password combination is invalid for Login. Thats ActiveDirectory, not SharePoint-related

Answer (score 0):

I think You should check in AD if user's password expired or not. I think user never logoff from the PC rather lock the PC. Do the following.

- Ask customer to Log off from PC  or even reboot it.
- Mean While check in AD, if user's password expired or not

User can login to SharePoint site as long as user's ID active and password never expired. I got these about to expire emails every other months for a week but no issue until it expired.